# Foot fault on a jump serve in volleyball

Tags: rules, terminology, volleyball

When a player does a jump serve can land on the baseline or not?

I had a case tonight when a player do a jump serve and landed on the baseline I was told it was not a foot fault, is it correct?

Comment: Proper jump serves are performed with a jump forward into the court to decrease the distance between server and receiver. If you watch good players make a jump serve you'll probably notice that.

Answer (score 6):

From [FIVB rules of the game](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB_Volleyball_Rules_2015-2016_EN_V3_20150205.pdf)

> 12.4.3 At the moment of the service hit or take-off for a jump service, the
>   server must not touch the court (the end line included) or the floor
>   outside the service zone.
>   **After the hit, he/she may step or land outside the service zone, or inside
>   the court.**

So in the case are your writing (landing on baseline *after* the hit) **it is not fault**